# why do all sound apps get  bluetooth button events, all at once

Tags: bluetooth, a2dp

If i have my phone (thunderbolt cyanogenmod7/2.3) connected to a bluetooth stereo and i hit the play button on the stereo, music, pandora, Subsonic, and Audible all start playing at once. pausing pauses all of them.

is there some way of controlling what apps respond to the buttons? 
is there an app to filter button events?

Comment: I suspect that they're all listening to a "Play Music" Intent. Our resident developers can probably shine some more light on this.

Comment: Interesting, on my OG Droid w/ CM7 it will occasionally decide to play from a random audio app when I press the lockscreen play button. I wonder if there's any relation.

Comment: Also see my related question: ["What determines which application acts to a bluetooth AVRCP command?"](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13620)

Answer (score 1):

The app [Media Button Router](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.harleensahni.android.mbr) is just what you are looking for. The app allows you to choose the media app you wish to control with the Bluetooth forward/reverse buttons using voice prompts.

The app doesn't work perfectly with all media apps, but I find that by playing with the settings you can usually overcome problems. But when it works it is magic!

Answer (score -1):

Check to see if all of those music processes are running. I would assume they all listen to play/pause events while active, maybe verifying that all but one are killed could get a response from just one.